# System.Windows.Controls.Theming.Toolkit

Tags: wpf, silverlight-2.0

I've seen some people that have managed to use the themes in the Silverlight 2.0 Toolkit in Windows WPF applications.  In fact, it looks like it's pretty easy...for them.  I've run into an odd issue early on in my attempts.

Here is all it take to fail:

- Create a new WPF Application project in VS2008 sp1
- Add a reference to System.Windows.Controls.Theming.Toolkit
- Rebuild all

System.Windows.Controls.Theming.Toolkit is loaded from:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v2.0\Toolkit\March 2009\Libraries

I get the following error:
c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.WinFX.targets(294,9): error MC1000: Unknown build error, 'The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

I understand the general meaning of the error, but I don't know what to do about it since it doesn't specify the version it wants and since it must be referenced from the newly added Assembly I don't know how to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this doesn't matter anymore.  When I was doing this the WPF Toolkit didn't include Microsoft's themes.  Now it does, and using those solves the problem.

Comment: I still don't see the System.Windows.Controls.Theming.Toolkit assembly in the latest WPF Toolkit. Where did you obtain this for WPF?

Comment: I haven't looked in a while but I believe it's just  System.Windows.Controls.Theming and each theme is in it's own assembly; e.g. System.Windows.Controls.Theming.ExpressionDark.